# Problema al instanciar una clase interna

Tags: java, clase, clase-anidada

Hola primero de todo estoy empezando a hacer colas y pilas así que soy nuevo. 
Mi problema esta cuando tengo que instanciar un objeto(?) de tipo pila(?) **Esta parte no la comprendo mucho teóricamente así que si podéis explicarla por favor os lo agradecería**.
El trozo que no me funciona es cuando me toca crear:

```
 Pila pila1 = new Pila();
```

Me lo marca como mal y no entiendo porque.

Os agradezco la ayuda.

```
public class pila_dinamica {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Pila pila1=new Pila();

    }

    public class Pila {

        class Nodo {
            int info;
            Nodo sig;
        }

        private Nodo raiz;

        public Pila() {
            raiz = null;
        }

        public void insertar(int x) {
            Nodo nuevo;
            nuevo = new Nodo();
            nuevo.info = x;
            if (raiz != null) {
                nuevo.sig = raiz;
                raiz = nuevo;
            } else {
                nuevo.sig = null;
                raiz = nuevo;

            }

        }

        public int extraer() {
            if (raiz != null) {
                int informacion = raiz.info;
                raiz = raiz.sig;
                return informacion;
            } else {
                return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
        }
        public void recorrer() {
            Nodo recor=raiz;
            System.out.println("Listado elementos de la pila :");
            while(recor.sig!=null) {
                System.out.println(recor.info);
                recor=recor.sig;
            }
        }
        public boolean vacia() {
          if(raiz!=null) {
              return true;
          }else {
              return false;
          }
        }
        public int cantidad() {
            int cant=0;
            Nodo reco=raiz;
            while(reco.sig!=null) {
                cant++;
                reco=reco.sig;
            }
            System.out.println("El numero de nodos que hay son :"+cant);
            return cant;
        }
        public int primernodo() {
            if(raiz!=null) {
                return raiz.info;
            }else {
                return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Deberías indicas **el error exacto** que *te marca*, y aclararlo: ¿ Quién *te lo marca* ? ¿ El IDE ? ¿ El compilador ?

Comment: ¿Eso es el mensaje que te sale, o la traducción que tú have del mensaje en inglés? En el segundo caso, por favor pon el mensaje original en inglés tal cual te sale.

Comment: Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing.

Comment: Por lo que dices, parece que necesitas buen material de apoyo. Si me lo permites, te recomiendo Java: Cómo programar Deitel & Deitel. Un saludo y ánimo, ninguno de los que estamos aquí nació sabiendo Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que estás utilizando se llama *clase interna*. En este caso, estás declarando una clase dentro de otra clase, lo que significa que cada vez que quieras instanciar esa clase *hija*, debes instanciar la clase *primero*.

Tienes dos opciones: instancias la clase *madre* antes de instanciar la clase hija.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Pila pila1 = new pila_dinamica().new Pila();

    }
```

O, en la declaración de tu clase, le agregas la palabra `static`, lo que también podrías instanciar la clase *hija* sin necesidad de instanciar la *madre*; quedando tu código así

```
public static class Pila {
```

Ojo, que solo lo podrías hacer dentro de la misma clase nomas.